# How do I read in and plot 3D data?

Tags: plotting, import

After reading the documentation, this was my first attempt:

```
import ["C:\\...\\pfc.dat", "Table"]
ListPlot3D[Table];
```

I get "arrayerr::Table must be a valid array or list of valid arrays".

The data is formatted like x,y,z e.g. 0,1,0.9

I realize this is simple but I don't understand why it is failing.

Comment: Have you tried `ListPointPlot3D`?

Comment: Table is a function, so you're supplying the ListPlot3D with a wrong argument.

Comment: Syntax you used makes no sense, type Import and press F1, examples there should clarify that.

Comment: mathematica is Case Sensative, `Import` not `import`.  Your data looks to be comma separated so read as `data = Import[file,"CSV"]` , then `ListPlot3D[data]`

Answer (score 2):

It looks simply like a syntax error. First of all, in MMA all commands are upper case, so you should do

```
data=Import["C:\\...\\pfc.dat","Table"]
```

Note a lack of space between `Import` and `["C:\\...\\pfc.dat","Table"]`.

Second, you want to plot a set of points, so instead using `ListPlot3D` you should use `ListPointPlot3D`.

Finally, you used `Table` as an argument of the plotting function, but as emphasized above, it is a built-in command. You should type

```
ListPointPlot3D[data]
```

possibly with any options you want - see @cyrille.piatecki's answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

As you are clearly a beginner I will decompose the process.

I suppose your file look like this one

```
 457.81 ,208.16 ,68.02
 46.71  ,8.69   ,2.99
 1198.97    ,195.99 ,3.99
 30.94  ,21.78  ,5.94
 4.43   ,6.64   ,4.95
-54.04  ,7.3    ,7.72
 127.70 ,42.76  ,6.22
-695.26 ,138.14 ,35
-226.36 ,4.98   ,8.33
```

you will see that the end of line is not specifically marked so one must provide to Mathematica the way to understand it.

Whichever be placed your file, you can load it with

```
l = ToString[Import["C:\\mypath\\data.txt"]]
```

This command read the file and transforms it in a string then we give a name to this string.

Now we want a string that looks like a List

```
l1 = StringSplit[l]
```

Unfortunately, this leads to the apparition of a not desired patern (, ,)
To eliminate it we replace it

```
l2 = StringReplace[l1, "," -> " "]
```

Then we want to reconstruct a table

```
l3 = Partition[l2, 3]
```

To finish we need to comme back to an expression because we want to plot it

```
l4 = ToExpression[l3]
```

You can observe that it is a matrix of 3 columns so one can plot it

```
ListPointPlot3D[l4, 
PlotStyle -> {Directive[GrayLevel[0], Opacity[0.406]], 
PointSize[0.05]}, Filling -> Bottom, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

Hope this fulfills your hopes.

Comment: Using simply `Import["path","Table"]` is sufficient - it imports exemplary data set without any problems.

Comment: wonderful, thank you